# Why Can't I change the Standard Input for Vim to some file on disk using redirection?

Tags: vim, io-redirection, stdin

I was reading the "[The UNIX Time- Sharing System Dennis M. Ritchie and Ken Thompson](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~brewer/cs262/unix.pdf)" paper and as an example for redirection of standard input/output, it gives the example of ed editor:

> The command `ed <script` interprets script as a file of editor commands;
>   thus “`<script`” means, “take input from `script`.”

How ever, if I try the same using vim, I get an error saying "Error reading input":

```
[m@localhost rough]$ vim t2 <t
Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal
Vim: Error reading input, exiting...
Vim: preserving files...
Vim: Finished.
```

Why is it so?

Comment: Is there a Vim script in the file `t`? Did you try `vim -s t t2`?

Comment: Maybe `ed` is just the superior editor?  :-)  (Modern `ed` should be used with its `-s` option when reading a script from standard input to turn off some of its more advanced interactive capabilities).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ed` and `ex` are *line editors*.  They have the sort of user interface that can be driven by lines in a text file.

`vi` and all of its clones such as VIM are *full screen editors*.  They have user interfaces that do not treat input and output as text file lines.  Input is individual characters and character sequences not grouped into lines.  Output is individual characters and escape and control sequences for drawing on a video terminal.

The model of *user I/O* as text files does not map to interactive full-screen TUI programs, let alone to GUI programs.

What behaviour you get varies from program to program.  Some full-screen TUI programs will recognize when their standard input is not a terminal, and abort, as `nvi` does.  Others, like VIM, will warn but will treat the non-terminal input file as terminal input, yielding somewhat odd behaviour for people who expect the input to be treated as script commands.  Yet others, like `less` for example, explicitly open a terminal device for the user interface and do not use standard I/O for (the input part) of it.  Yet others still, like most shells (which, note, have interactive user interfaces that are more than line mode), drop to a non-interactive mode.

A paper written about Unix in 1974 will not be a good guide to the difference between line-mode user interfaces and full-screen user interfaces.  Possibly the first Unix editor for video terminals, George Coulouris' `em`, was a year in the future.  Also in the future were termcap, shells with (their own) command line editing, and line discipline defaults that used non-graphic special characters.

Comment: thanks for the comprehensive answer.